# Return code of JNI_CreateJavaVM

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I found the http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html

was the documentation of JNI call funcitons.

But for example if I call:

```
JNI_CreateJavaVM
```

There is this technotes:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#JNI_CreateJavaVM

I know the return code is a jint telling me:

- if the return of the function is 0 ok
- if the return of the funciton is negative is not ok or some issue.

The above documentation of the method JNI_CreateJavaVM says:

```
RETURNS:
Returns JNI_OK on success; returns a suitable JNI error code (a negative number) on failure.
```

But I dont know exactly what is the the real result because it does not say the possible error codes.

**So I can't create any JVM because it gives me a *jvm pointer null, and the ERROR CODE is -1.**

Is there a "javadoc" of JNI?

Comment: This is a request for an off-site resource, which is off-topic.

Comment: Maybe not because it's coding error problem not a resource stuff.

Comment: You're already looking at the official JNI specifications (don't let the "technotes" in its URL fool you).  As far as I know, there is no official documentation of the error codes to which the doc refers.  But this seems to be an X-Y problem: the real question appears to be "Why do my `JNI_CreateJavaVM()` calls always fail?"  If you present a [mcve], then we may be of more help with that one.

Comment: Always fail. I'll try put more info... Is this all the documentation about this method? It's failrure. How can I know what error code is? Shouldn't be this in somewhere? Should I download the JNI c++ source code to check the error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`jni.h` defines the possible return values for JNI functions:

```
#define JNI_OK           0                 /* success */
#define JNI_ERR          (-1)              /* unknown error */
#define JNI_EDETACHED    (-2)              /* thread detached from the VM */
#define JNI_EVERSION     (-3)              /* JNI version error */
#define JNI_ENOMEM       (-4)              /* not enough memory */
#define JNI_EEXIST       (-5)              /* VM already created */
#define JNI_EINVAL       (-6)              /* invalid arguments */
```

Comment: is jni.c or jni.cpp (the implementation) available in somewhere?

Comment: @felipe here is is the openjdk version: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp